# Searching a key word with java client programme from wsdl

Tags: java, web-services

Heyy I have a problem

I generated a client programme using http://api.search.live.net/search.wsdl this service for searching a key words..
I generated client by help of Eclipse-web project from this service.
I have done searched on this service(live.net) but ı can't show on the console. How ı can do that?

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

```
LiveSearchPortTypeProxy bb=new LiveSearchPortTypeProxy();

SearchRequest request=new SearchRequest();

SearchRequestType1 bbs=new SearchRequestType1();

aas.setParameters(request);

sorgu.setAppId("*****************************************"); //you can take this ID from live service for using this service

sorgu.setSources(new SourceType[]{SourceType.Web});

sorgu.setQuery("keyword");

SearchResponseType0 cevap= bb.search(bbs);





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cevap variable and its public get methods in a debugger, and see what you have.

You will most likely end up with an instance of org.w3c.Node which represents the root of the parsed response.  This can then be treated like any other DOM tree.